# Как в Android прямо из кода программно создать новый Activity class?

Tags: java, android

Нужно это для бесконечной навигации вглубь. На каждой из активностей список, по клику на элемент списка мы переходим на новую активность со списком и так до бесконечности.

Comment: Это не имеет смысла - логику (код) класса ведь всё равно нужно продумать заранее, а значит и класс можно написать заранее. Другой вопрос, что можно запустить несколько копий одной `Activity` с разными данными, но это тоже не лучший выход - память то не бесконечная. Лучше менять данные в одной `Activity`, запоминая историю переходов по дереву данных.

Answer (score 4):

Это невозможно сделать. Точнее, такое не реализовать, в смысле невозможности программного создания разных активити, т.к. они должны быть зарегистрированы в манифесте, а он упаковывается в АПК на этапе компиляции.

Бесконечную навигацию можно реализовать на фрагментах. Но и их классы у вас не получится генерировать на лету. Только использовать уже имеющиеся, просто отображать в них различные данные.